# How to set logging environment for a module in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a python module of the following structure

```
|- src
  |- a
    |- aa
      |- x.py
      |- y.py
    |- ab
      |- xx.py
  |- b
    |- ba
      |- xxx.py
```

In the `.py` files, I have loggings like

```
logging.INFO("A")
logging.DEBUG("B")
```

I'm thinking to add a global control of the loggings for the whole module. I would like to set up a global logging level, say `.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. Where should I do this? I have tried to put an `__init__.py` file in the `src` folder setting the logging level, but it seems to have no effect when I import functions from the `.py` files.

I'm wondering

- what is a good way to do this? The level should work when someone uses for example `from a.aa.x import A`.
- When I use `logger = logging.getLogger()` in each `.py` file, are the `logger`'s all the same?
- What's the benefit of using different loggers (say `logger = logging.getLogger(".a")` and `logger = logging.getLogger(".b")` in different `.py` files)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `logging.log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)` to replace `logging.INFO` and `logging.DEBUG()` and define a variable for `level` globally and change that according to your need.

For me, I made a function for my own project

```
def log_message(message, level="INFO"):
    logging_levels = {
        "CRITICAL": 50,
        "ERROR": 40,
        "WARNING": 30,
        "INFO": 20,
        "DEBUG": 10
    }
    level = level.upper()
    level = logging_levels[level] if level in logging_levels else 20
    print(message)
    logger.log(level, message)
```

This helps to both print and log the message I want, while I can easily intercept all the logs in this function.

> When I use `logger = logging.getLogger()` in each `.py` file, are the `logger`'s all the same?

Yes

> What's the benefit of using different loggers?

I don't think you should, but I supposed that can help you to better categorize the logs?

Reference: [Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! I'm wondering where can I control the default logging level? For example some logs are `DEBUG` and I don't want them to be logged by default when I do `from a.aa.x import A`. Should I declare a default logging level in each of the `.py` files?

Comment: Or maybe that's not possible, it depends on the new session where I have `from a.aa.x import A`. If I don't use `logging.setLevel()` there, the default level will always be `INFO`.